# How to remove an element in linked list Java even if there is duplication?

Tags: java

For example, remove 5, `11 21 5 5 31 41`, after remove `[ 11 21 31 41 ]`.

This method will look for the item I need to remove in linked list and also remove any duplication for that item.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

Don't stop looping through the linked list when you delete the first item. Loop until you reach the end and delete every instance of the item you are looking for on the way.

Comment: After you remove an element, the indices get "pushed" to the left, though. Will that work? I am guessing this is the issue he has.

Comment: Wait you are using the standard libs implementation of LinkedList? `while(list.remove(object));`

Comment: If you `list.remove(index)` the element that previously had its index as `index+1` will have it as `index` now, right?

Comment: Ofc, but don't use `list.remove(index)`, use `list.remove(object)`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some test code.  Here are the results.

```
[11, 21, 5, 5, 31, 41]
[11, 21, 31, 41]
```

The trick to doing this is to iterate through the List from the back to the front.  That way, you don't have to worry about adjusting indexes.

The easier way would be to use the list.remove(value) method.  But this method is effective if you're checking one field in a Java object, rather than Integer as I'm doing in this example.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListRemove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = { 11, 21, 5, 5, 31, 41 };
        List<Integer> list = createList(values);
        System.out.println(list);
        new ListRemove().remove(list, 5);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static List<Integer> createList(int[] values) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(values.length);

        for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            list.add(Integer.valueOf(values[index]));
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void remove(List<Integer> list, int value) {
        for (int index = list.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            if (list.get(index) == value) {
                list.remove(index);
            }
        }
    }

}
```